# How to apply MVVM correctly in this case?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im migrating an application from Windows Forms to WPF, so I am trying to use the MVVM pattern, but it is getting a bit tricky to me.

In Windows forms I have a form which contains a progressBar which has defined some new methods that allow me to perform steps, set its value, etc. This code is placed in the progressBar's code behind as below:

```
public class MyProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public MyProgressBar ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Method01()
    {...}

    public void Method02()
    {...}

    public void Method03()
    {...}
}
```

The code of the Method01, Method02 and Method03 is used in the container form, so, here is my question: In WPF, since I use the MVVM pattern, Where do I have to place that code??

Until now I have this classes:

My model:

```
public class MyFormModel : DataTable
{
    public OutputResultsDataTable()
        : base()
    {
        Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Number"));
        Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Message"));
        Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Detail"));
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class MyNewWPFForm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public MyFormModel MyData{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public MyNewWPFForm()
    {
        if (System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow != null)
        {
            MyData= new MyFormModel ();                
        }
    }
}
```

In WPF I have already created my new progressBar control and its container form, even I have been reading about MVVM but I cant understand where do I have to put the code of the Method0X, because, according to what I have read, I would have to put that code in the viewModel, but, here is another problem: How could I have access to my progress bar from my view model since it is inside another form??

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are Method01,2,3 supposed to do?

Comment: I think this post will be of benefit to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619505/wpf-openfiledialog-with-the-mvvm-pattern

Comment: @DaveHillier, Since I have a listView either Method0X allow me to insert rows directly, copy content to clipboard, perform an step in the progressBar, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the methods on your control are used for setting state of your control. You could use [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428.aspx) to do this.

You use binding to connect your view to your view model.

Create a property for your controls progress.

Then in Xaml add a binding

```
<MyProgressBar Progress="{Binding CurrentProgress}" />
```

Set the data context of your view to a new view model. 
CurrentProgress is a property on the view model.
Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) on your view model.

For adding and removing things to/from your control you might [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).