# How to write test case for Dialog services MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am new very new to MVVM and i am following MVVM Light toolkit.
To implement a message box functionality i searched and got this [example](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/dialogservice-in-mvvm-light-v5/)

The points i didn't understand is

1. Class **DialogService** is what we should create by inheriting **IDialogService** ??

If that is the case for example in the class after inheriting the interface we need to write something like below

```
 public Task<bool> ShowMessage(string message, string title, string buttonConfirmText, string buttonCancelText, Action<bool> afterHideCallback)
 {
            //Here a kind of this implemetation i need to do ?
            //For example sake i didn't include the parameters.
  MessageBox.Show();
 }
```

> If the above is true in the view model we will just
>   dialogueServices.ShowMessage(prms....) ?
>   So how this can be tested ?

For instance if it is filebrowser , if we invoke this way in unit test as per understanding it will open a file browser.
How this can be implemented?

Since i am very to this pattern itself i am finding difficulty in understanding.

Please provide a sample implementation or any reference.

**EDIT**

I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619505/wpf-openfiledialog-with-the-mvvm-pattern) also. In comment it was told its responsibility of a view.
I was more confused. In general at least for confirmation dialog's how would we do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix UI logic in your ViewModel/Business logic.
You should seperate concerns like business logic, UI logic.

I suggest you to use MvvmLight Messenger facilities. Your ViewModel should publish message "there is an informational dialog to show" and appropiate view should register, listen and handle this message.

Example:

ViewModel

```
public void SomeViewModelMethod() {
     if (somethingWentWrong)
        Messenger.Default.Publish(new ShowInformationalDialogMessage(title,msg));
}
```

View

```
.. OnLoaded { 
   Messenger.Default.Register<ShowInformationalDialogMessage>( () => {
      UI LOGIC CODE
   });
}
```

To test this case you should just register to published message in your unit test class and assert that this message logic has been executed.