# How can I assign text to a TextBlock that is read from a file when clicking a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My app has to load a `.txt` file from the file system, read it and put its text into a `TextBlock`, but I don't know how to connect my `Button` to my view model so my text block that is bound to a property in it displays this text.

Let's repeat what I want my app to do:

1. A user clicks on the load button and he chooses a `.txt` file
2. The text from the file is assigned to the `NumbersString` property
3. The text block loads this text from  the `NumbersString` property

I dont know how to get step 2 to work.

XAML

```
<Button Name="load" Background="Pink" Click="load_Click">Load File</Button>

<TextBox x:Name="numbers1" Text="{Binding NumbersString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Code-behind XAML

There is a mistake my view model property `NumbersString`. It should be connected to the button.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = new numbersViewModel();
   }

   public void load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
      if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
         NumbersString = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
   }
}
```

View model

```
class numbersViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private numbersModel _model;

   protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler evt = PropertyChanged;
      if (evt != null)
         evt(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
   
   // iI want my text block to take the string from here
   public string NumbersString
   {
      get { return _model.numbersString; }
      set
      {
         if (value != _model.numbersString)
         {
            _model.numbersString = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("numbers1");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Model

```
private string model="";
public string numbersString
{
   get
   {
      return model;
   }

   set
   {
      model = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: `RaisePropertyChanged("numbers1")` => `RaisePropertyChanged("NumbersString")`

Comment: where should i put this?, in code behind xaml ?

Comment: Just fix the bug in `PropertyChanged` call. About button+MVVM, refer to this: [Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622980/12888024).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You raise the property changed event for `numbers1` in your `NumbersString` property, therefore the change for the wrong property (that does not even exist) is triggered, but that will not update the `TextBox`.

Adapt the property name in the call to `RaisePropertyChanged`. You can use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) instead of a hardcoded `string`.

```
public string NumbersString
{
   get { return _model.numbersString; }
   set
   {
      if (value != _model.numbersString)
      {
         _model.numbersString = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(NumbersString));
      }
   }
}
```

Since you are using a mix of code-behind and MVVM, you could set the `NumbersString` property in your event handler like this:

```
public void load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
   if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
      ((numbersViewModel)DataContext).NumbersString = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

The last bit to make it work is that you never create or assign an instance of a `numbersModel` to the `_model` property on `numbersViewModel`. You *could* do that in the constructor.

```
public numbersViewModel(numbersModel numbersModel)
{
   _model = numbersModel;
}
```

### An MVVM approach using commands

Instead of using event handlers for button clicks, you should use commands. You can copy the `RelayCommand` class that [@aepot linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic). First, you create an `ICommand` property in your `numbersViewModel`.

```
public ICommand LoadFile { get; }
```

`RelayCommand` implements the `ICommand` interface and delegates the execution logic to a method that you have to pass when creating it in the constructor of `numbersViewModel`:

```
public numbersViewModel(numbersModel numbersModel)
{
   _model = numbersModel;
   LoadFile = new RelayCommand(ExecuteLoadFile);
}
```

The `ExecuteLoadFile` method contains the logic for loading the file and reading its text. In practice, this would also violate MVVM priciples as this method is located in a view model and `OpenFileDialog` is a view type. You would extract this part into a service with an interface, so that the view model does not know about its implementation, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

```
private void ExecuteLoadFile(object obj)
{
   var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
   if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
      NumbersString = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

Finally, bind the `Command` property on your button to the `LoadFile` command.

```
<Button Name="load" Background="Pink" Content="Load File" Command="{Binding LoadFile}"/>
```

With these changes you can remove the event handler from your `MainWindow`.

Comment: Correct answer, very easy but violates MVVM. What about `ICommand` usage?

Comment: @aepot I have updated the answer to include an approach using commands.

Comment: Much better now :)